# LAN version of OnLive/Gaikai

Tags: streaming, real-time

I'm patiently following news about [OnLive](http://www.onlive.com) and [Gaikai](http://www.gaikai.com) type solutions, especially their (slooooow) way to Europe/Germany.

I currently own a pretty beefy PC for almost games-only. But as many people my main work and internet device is a rather weak laptop.

So is their any solution to basically stream my desktop/game in realtime to another pc in my LAN?

Shouldn't this be possible if these guys can do it over the internet? Especially Gaikai boasts that it only uses commodity hardware to do its magic.

During my research I found that streaming your desktop is actually possible with VLC but I am not sure if it is real-time enough for this kind of application. The input could be done with a tool like Synergy, which as far as I can tell is pretty much instantaneous.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3):

If you own an iPad, you can use [everyAir](http://www.everyair.net/) :

> everyAir is a remote desktop
>   application that is designed to let
>   you smoothly play games and rich
>   media. With everyAir you'll be able to
>   play World of Warcraft, Starcraft 2,
>   or any other game -- all on your iPad.
>   You'll also finally have streaming
>   Flash videos and games at 30+ frames
>   per second. If you wanted to use your
>   business productivity apps, you could
>   do that, too. But then with so many
>   fun options, why would you want to?
>
> everyAir's unbelievable performance is
>   possible because of our proprietary
>   server technology. Rather than relying
>   on VNC or RDP, we architected from the
>   ground-up a new way of handling remote
>   desktop connectivity.
>
> We have a slew of features planned, so
>   for a limited time only, the app is
>   $4.99 until we add iPhone and iPod
>   touch support. Get in at this
>   introductory rate and your iPhone
>   update will be free!
>
> Operating Systems supported in this
>   version: All versions of Win7, all
>   versions of Vista, all versions of XP.
>   We'll have OSX support coming very
>   soon.
>
> This release of everyAir is optimized
>   to work over local wi-fi.

Comment: This answer may have been useful, but it is not anymore. everyAir has been acquired. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: @lochok: Just google for "everyAir alternatives". For example [this](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1585788).

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to achieve this for years. Here is my take after 5 years; there are couple options:

1. Kainy

   [Kainy](http://www.kainy.com/) is an application just has created for this purpose. In fact, it aims to play games over 3G network so it will run on Android and Chrome too. I must say, It's pretty impressive. It is a bit hard to adjust settings but it works. It has even a game launcher screen and can detect the game window automatically and zoom to it. Downside is, I didn't see any update from the developer.
2. Remote Desktop Solutions

   Splashtop can work over LAN and Internet and it is great for this purpose. It can capture game screen very fast. Downside is, some features require montly subscription. However, if you can do VPN to your PC, you wouldn't need to pay anything.

   TeamViewer sometimes can recognize fast moving windows like games and deliver adeque performance but I wouln't use it except for turn based games.

   Windows Remote Desktop can work with accelerated graphics via [RemoteFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX) but it requires a server and additional configuration.
3. Steam

   Steam has built-in in  house streaming feature for computers connected over network. You can host your game on your powerful PC, and stream it to less powerful ones.

Everything is fine over LAN, the biggest issue is upload speed and only couple of options work well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried off-the-shelf [remote desktop programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software)?